# Where is my cloned MITK?

Tags: c++, itk, mitk

I'm going through this [tutorial](http://docs.mitk.org/nightly-qt4/BuildInstructionsPage.html#BuildInstructions_Prerequisites). I have performed the following command to clone `MITK`:

```
git clone http://git.mitk.org/MITK.git
```

I'm using a `Windows` machine. Where can I find the cloned directory on my machine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends on where you cloned it. On Windows git console opens in C:\Users\username\ folder by default. So, look in C:\Users\username\MITK.

Type pwd in git console to see where you are.